# Pig Latin Remove Tuple in Data Bag

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Here is my code leading up to my issue:

```
 a = LOAD 'tellers' using TextLoader() AS line;
 # convert a to charrarry
 b = foreach a generate (chararray)line;  
 # run through my UDF to create tuples
 c = foreach b generate myudfs.TellerParser5(line);  # ({(20),(5),(5),(10)(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(5),(10),(10),(10)})....
 d = foreach c generate flatten(number); 
 e = group d by number; #{group: chararray,d: {(number: chararray)}}
 f = foreach e generate group, COUNT(d);  # f: {group: chararray,long}
```

In databag f, I have an empty tuple (,1) I'd like to filter/remove.

```
 dump f;
 (,1)
 (1,97)
 (5,49)
 (10,87)
 (20,24)

 describe f;
 f: {group: chararray,long}
```

I've tried this with no success (makes no change):

```
 remove_tuple = filter f BY group is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Group is a pig `keyword`. Hope this should work when some other word is used for the tuple name.

Comment: how do I change the tuple name?  The reason why it's "group" is the way I created the data bag "e".  So above for my edited code for that.

Comment: Change that "e" in the first script itself and try..... U should not be using keyword as tuple name anywhere....

Answer (score 0):

NULL can be filtered by using `!='null'` as a condition. I have taken below as the input.

```
(,1)
(1,97)
(5,49)
(10,87)
(20,24)
```

Below is how we can filter NULL's.

```
A = LOAD 'file' using PigStorage(',') AS (a:chararray,b:long);
B = FILTER A BY a!='null';
DUMP B;
```

So for your script the line will be something like

```
 remove_tuple = filter f BY group!='null';
```

Output:

```
(1,97)
(5,49)
(10,87)
(20,24)
```

Comment: Sorry i missed the quote can you try now. Updated the answer.

Comment: Should be getting the result. Post your whole script with input and expected output.

Comment: I again tried with my input and for f my schema is same as that of your's f: {group: chararray,long}. And then applied the filter remove_tuple = filter f BY group!='null'; when i dump it removes the NULL.

Comment: perhaps it's not considered a null

Comment: then if it is a blank then give a try with remove_tuple = filter f BY group!='';

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding a step and casting as an int.  Here are the steps:

```
 e = foreach d generate (int)$0; # this is the key added step

 f = group e by number; #{group: chararray,d: {(number: chararray)}}
 g = foreach f generate group, COUNT(e);  # f: {group: chararray,long}
 h = foreach f generate group, SUM(e);
 i = filter g by $0 is not null; 
 dump i; 
 (1,97)
 (5,49)
 (10,87)
 (20,24)
```